# How to hide a datalist's options using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-datalist

Given the following code:

```
<label for="myBrowser">Choose a browser from this list:</label>
<input list="browsers" id="myBrowser" name="myBrowser" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

The following UI is rendered:

[image: input box with dropdown suggestions]

What CSS can be added *without changing the HTML* and *without using JavaScript* to take away the auto-completed items so it behaves like a datalist-less input?

The following UI is desired:

[image: input box without dropdown suggestions]

Answer (score 0):

It is not solved with css, but try use `autocomplete="off"` in your input

Comment: That requires me to change the HTML, so this does not answer my question.